# InApp products failed to load on only ipv6

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ipv6

My app was rejected due to reason that in-app products failed to load on `ipv6` network, however on `ipv4` network it is working fine. What could be the issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error a month ago, I updated `AFNetworking` library and Apple's `Reachability` classes, after this process my problem is solved, you can try this, I hope it'll work.

Comment: it's irrelevant about your problem. Everyone using `StoreKit` for IAP.